# Is Application Context in Spring Framework user specific or application specific?

Tags: java, spring, applicationcontext

Is application context you load from .xml file is user specific level or application level, like context is once loaded for all the user? or every user has separate application context?

while using spring framework in java?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The context is application-wide, but individual beans can have narrower scopes.

The most common scopes are

- singleton (default: one per application)
- prototype (a new bean is created each time one is requested)
- request (one bean per HTTP request)
- session (one bean per HTTP session)

Obviously, the latter two types are user-specific beans.

**Reference:**

- [Bean Scopes](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-scopes)

Answer (score 1):

It's application-specific, it applies to the entire application.

Answer (score 0):

The application context is application level.  It doesn't really make sense to talk about it as being tied to users.